# Distancing (Main) - What does "Main" mean here?

Tags: word-usage

I just found the snowflake icon on the right upper cornor of this forum appearing a notice that shows "Winter Bash" (does it mean "Winter Party"?), and upon clicking it, the opened page shows "Distancing (Main)"- I wonder what does "main" means here. Dictionaries have a definition for it:"power". Not sure it is the definition in need. Coincidently, I won a gold badge. So I guess "main" might refer to the gold badge. I am not sure.

What does "main" mean here?

> Distancing (Main)
> Visit any question page on any site. Earn once per main site.
> show controls

Comment: Bash means "party", but it's slang

Comment: https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/ - click this link to know more on Winer Bash.

Comment: That's ***Social** Distancing* - on the ***main*** site rather than ***ELLL meta***. Apparently the way to "win" that hat is ***Visit any question page on any site. Earn once per main site.***

Answer (score 2):

**Winter Bash** is equivalent to 'winter party'.

> **bash** - *a party or gathering*. [Source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bash)

**Social Distancing (Main)** means the main site, which is this, [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

**Social Distancing (Meta)** represents the Meta site, [ELL.Meta](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/).

This doesn't have to do anything with the Gold Badge you received for a question crossing 10K views.